# Are "prenda" and "ropa" the same?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, sinónimos

Both *prenda* and *ropa* mean clothing. Although **prenda** also means jewelry in Venezuela but in general contexts, it seems to be synonymous to *ropa*. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Prenda* is normally an article of clothing and thereby countable, whereas *ropa* is clothing in general and not normally countable (unless you're talking about the various types of clothing, in which case it is).

- Me compré ropa ayer. (cuantidad desconocida)
- Me compré dos ropas ayer. (poco común)
- Me compré una prenda ayer. (una pieza)
- Me compré dos prendas ayer. (dos piezas)

This is the general usage in Spain, however, there may very well be some regional differences.

Comment: This is also true for the Spanish in Colombia, with the exception that the second example would be considered unacceptable: `... dos ropas ...`. For us "ropa" is always uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

> Me compré una **prenda** de **ropa**.

*Prenda* se podría aceptar como una unidad de medida para la *ropa*.

En la tienda, te preguntan:

> ¿Cuantas **prendas** se lleva?